# Can a HTMLElement.click() be limited to a certain amount of times used?

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach, onclick, jquery-selectors

I have a script for a bookmarklet below given to me by a gentlemen that was very helpful, and I was hoping to understand if I could limit the script to only "clicking" a max of 25 times, or perhaps to slow down each "click" with a wait time of some sort, but where would I include this?

```js
javascript:(
  function(){
    document.querySelectorAll(`path[stroke-linecap='round']`).forEach(
      el => {el.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.click()}
    )
  })
()
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
javascript: (
  function() {
    const arr = [...document.querySelectorAll(`path[stroke-linecap='round']`)];
    const iterations = 25;
    let cnt = Math.min(iterations, arr.length);
    for (let ele of arr) {
      if (cnt-- > 0) ele.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.click();
      else break;
    }
  })()
```

Slowing it down

```js
javascript: (
  function() {
    const arr = document.querySelectorAll(`path[stroke-linecap='round']`);
    const speed = 500; /* milliseconds */
    const iterations = 25;
    let cnt = Math.min(iterations, arr.length);
    const tId = setInterval(function() {
      if (cnt-- <= 0) clearInterval(tId);
      else arr[cnt].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.click();
    }, 500)
  })()
```

Comment: yes! Very close! was the let cnt = 25 the variable to change in order to speed it up or slow it down or limit it further to say 10 or 15 if needed? Thank you!

Comment: I added a setInterval